# Httpwebrequst cookie not being set in POST

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Im trying to post a form but i keep getting an error when i look at the returned html code saying

> Cookies must be enabled in order to submit the form

I use the following code to submit the form:

```
                string postData = "submit_hidden=submit_hidden&captcha_item_key=" + captcha_item_key + "&security_code=" + lastCaptcha + "&submit=Submit";
            byte[] _data = _enc.GetBytes(postData);
            _wReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlen);
            _wReq.Referer = urlen;
            _wReq.CookieContainer = myContainer;
            _wReq.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
            _wReq.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
            _wReq.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
            _wReq.KeepAlive = true;
            _wReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";


            _wReq.Method = "POST";
            _wReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            _wReq.ContentLength = _data.Length;

            System.IO.Stream _outStream = _wReq.GetRequestStream();
            _outStream.Write(_data, 0, _data.Length);
            _outStream.Close();
            _wResp = (HttpWebResponse)_wReq.GetResponse();
            _sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(_wResp.GetResponseStream());
            _respStr = _sr.ReadToEnd();
            _sr.Close();
            _wResp.Close();
```

I am saving the cookie into a cookie container so im not sure why its not working?

Javascript is not the problem as ive tried to submit the form from a browser without having Javascript activated.

Also checked the submittion with Fiddler and the only thing that differes from a browser with my method is that the cookie for some reason does not get set properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: how are you adding cookie in your myContainer

Comment: Im setting the cookie in my get request